# Wireless Adapters for Testing with BackTrack

Tags: penetration-test, wifi, incident-response, injection, kali-linux

I would like to begin testing and working with BackTrack.  I have heard that the [Alfa AWUS036H](http://www.alfa.com.tw/in/front/bin/ptdetail.phtml?Part=AWUS036H&Category=105479) wireless adapter works well with BackTrack and allows for packet injection.  This adapter, however, is only a wireless b/g adapter.  I was curious if there was something similar to this adapter that would allow for packet injection, work on Windows and Linux (especially BackTrack), and would support wireless b/g/n?  Support for wireless a would be a plus too, but not a requirement.  Also, are there any replacement antenna's that one should consider using with this device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first place to look would be the BackTrack wiki: http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Drivers

There is also a strong community who will provide guidance on the Backtrack forums.

Answer (score 0):

I personally used the following [http://www.amazon.com/Edimax-EW-7811Un-150Mbps-Raspberry-Supports/dp/B003MTTJOY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MTTJOY) with no issues. combining this with hostapd on top of Kali Linux gives you a very powerful wireless pentesting infrastructure